# HttpContext.User is always null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to access the User of the HttpContext via `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User`.
Unfortunately, it is always `null`.

In my `launchSettings.json` I have windowsAuthentication set to true and anonymousAuthentication to false.

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/Sw.Intranet.Webclient",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55425",
      "sslPort": 44340
    }
  }, 
[...]
}
```

In my Startup, I have the middleware configured in this order:

- app.UseRouting()
- app.UseAuthorization()
- app.UseEndpoints(...)

I have configured the HttpContextAccessor: `services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Is there anything else I could check / I have missed why the User is always null?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What webserver are you using? IIRC only IIS (not IIS Express, not Kestrel) supports Windows Authentication. Also, try using Internet Explorer - I'm unsure to what extent Chrome (and Edge) support Windows Authentication.

Comment: Did you also add `app.UseAuthentication();` in the middleware?

Comment: Make sure you also install Websockets protocol on IIS as it can also cause httpContextAccessor to have null values. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538132/httpcontext-is-null-when-running-web-app-in-iis