# Get remote IP address in Blazor server-side app running in IIS does not work?

Tags: javascript, c#, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to get the IP address of the client, so I did the following:

1. Created a controller and added this action:

   ```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public ActionResult IpAddress()
    {
        var remoteIpAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        if (remoteIpAddress != null)
            return Ok(remoteIpAddress.ToString());

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
   ```
2. Added the following script to my `site.js`:

   ```
    window.getIpAddress = () => {
        return fetch('/api/utils/ipaddress')
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((data) => {
                return data
            })
    }
   ```
3. Set up `Startup.cs` to user controllers too, also adding the following:

   ```
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
   ```
4. And finally, added the following to my razor component:

   ```
    var ipAddress = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getIpAddress").ConfigureAwait(true);
   ```

I then publish to IIS and access the app.

However, the IP address is not the client's IP address (actually the value of standard gateway) but that of the machine where IIS is running!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441521/remoteipaddress-is-always-null) (particularly the answer to the second one).

Comment: @sellotape Nope doesn't work

Comment: @Ivan-Mark Debono, here's your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538319/6152891 . It is also relevant to this question of yours(https://stackoverflow.com/q/66553818/6152891) . Please, let me know if you did not succeed to solve your issues

Comment: @enet I was actually already using that same procedure to get the `ITrackingConsentFeature`, so I just added the IPAddress. However, it's still the server machine's gateway and not the client IP address :(

Comment: @Ivan-Mark Debono, I'll inspect things, and let you know when I get a  proper solution

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: @Ivan-Mark Debono, please go to github and respond to the comment by BrennanConroy. He's not of the Blazor team, but he's the one who can help.
,